# Can I install Ubuntu on computers and sell them?

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows-xp, legal

I want to sell second hand computers, I buy them cheap, upgrade them with parts from broken computers I get free and then sell them for a profit (not much, about 20-30 € profit).

Now, I used to install Windows XP because almost all the pc's I get, have an OEM Win XP licence with it. Now support for Windows XP is ending, it will be very hard to sell an Win XP computer.

Am I allowed to install Ubuntu on the machines and sell them with Ubuntu and XP dualboot?